# Add array same as new value to another array php

Tags: php, wordpress, elementor

I want to create custom widget for elementor . In this widget user can create a image slider and create some markers on every image. so i created a repeater control for images and another one for markers . In markers repeater i added a selector that user can select image and add marker to selected image.

Images repeater output :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [image_title] => Image 1
            [_id] => fe58385
            [image_url] => Array
                (
                    [url] => ../wp-content/uploads/2023/05/big-pic-1.png
                    [id] => 1326
                    [size] => 
                    [alt] => 
                    [source] => library
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [image_title] => Image 2
            [_id] => 40a0cc6
            [image_url] => Array
                (
                    [url] => ../wp-content/uploads/2023/05/big-pic-2.png
                    [id] => 1327
                    [size] => 
                    [alt] => 
                    [source] => library
                )

        )

)
```

And Markers output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [marker_title] => mark1-1
            [marker_top] => 40
            [marker_left] => 100
            [_id] => 6763ae7
            [marker_parent] => 0
            [marker_desc] => Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ne est populo dictas, et pri ferri ubique labitur.

Mel ad euismod adipiscing moderatius eos an decore quodsi animal.
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [marker_title] => mark2-1
            [marker_top] => 60
            [marker_left] => 100
            [marker_parent] => 0
            [marker_desc] => Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ne est populo dictas, et pri ferri ubique labitur.

Mel ad euismod adipiscing moderatius eos an decore quodsi animal.
            [_id] => 9d1b611
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [marker_title] => mark1-2
            [marker_top] => 40
            [marker_left] => 100
            [marker_parent] => 1
            [marker_desc] => Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ne est populo dictas, et pri ferri ubique labitur.

Mel ad euismod adipiscing moderatius eos an decore quodsi animal.
            [_id] => 6030c28
        )

)
```

in markers you can see [marker_parent] value that selected image by user(use for check image index).
i want to add markers to Images array as new value like ['markers'] that belong to correct image.

how can i resolved it?

I wrote this loop to do that :

```
$settings = $this->get_settings_for_display();
$images = $settings['images'];
$markers = $settings['markers'];
foreach ($images as $key=>$image) :
   if($key == $markers['marker_parent']){
         $image['marker'] = $markers[$key];
   }
endforeach;
```

Comment: Try passing by reference in your foreach loop: `$key => &$image`

Comment: @JacobMulquin It's not work. my problem is when i add marks to image same as ['mark']=>[mark1,mark2,mak3,...] just first mark added .

Comment: `if($key == $markers['marker_parent'])` - that will never be true, $markers does not have any key `marker_parent` on the top level. You need to loop over your individual markers here as well.

Comment: @CBroe yeah i know it. but $key is value key of $images array. see in this line "foreach ($images as $key=>$image)". also Jacob Mulquin resolved this issue.Thanks to share your comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand what you want, this code will map the `markers` array to the `images` array based on the `marker_parent` field being the index of the images array.

```
<?php

/*

Question Author: Vahab Mohammadi
Question Answerer: Jacob Mulquin
Question: Add array same as new value to another array php
URL: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76435799/add-array-same-as-new-value-to-another-array-php
Tags: php, wordpress, elementor

*/

$settings = $this->get_settings_for_display();
$images = $settings['images'];
$markers = $settings['markers'];

$markers_map = [];
foreach ($markers as $marker) {
    if (!isset($markers_map[$marker['marker_parent']])) {
        $markers_map[$marker['marker_parent']] = [];
    }
    $markers_map[$marker['marker_parent']][] = $marker;
}

foreach ($markers_map as $index => $map) {
    $images[$index]['markers'] = $map;
}

print_r($images);
```

Yields:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [image_title] => Image 1
            [_id] => fe58385
            [image_url] => Array
                (
                    [url] => ../wp-content/uploads/2023/05/big-pic-1.png
                    [id] => 1326
                    [size] => 
                    [alt] => 
                    [source] => library
                )

            [markers] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [marker_title] => mark1-1
                            [marker_top] => 40
                            [marker_left] => 100
                            [_id] => 6763ae7
                            [marker_parent] => 0
                            [marker_desc] => Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ne est populo dictas, et pri ferri ubique labitur.

Mel ad euismod adipiscing moderatius eos an decore quodsi animal.
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [marker_title] => mark2-1
                            [marker_top] => 60
                            [marker_left] => 100
                            [marker_parent] => 0
                            [marker_desc] => Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ne est populo dictas, et pri ferri ubique labitur.

Mel ad euismod adipiscing moderatius eos an decore quodsi animal.
                            [_id] => 9d1b611
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [image_title] => Image 2
            [_id] => 40a0cc6
            [image_url] => Array
                (
                    [url] => ../wp-content/uploads/2023/05/big-pic-2.png
                    [id] => 1327
                    [size] => 
                    [alt] => 
                    [source] => library
                )

            [markers] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [marker_title] => mark1-2
                            [marker_top] => 40
                            [marker_left] => 100
                            [marker_parent] => 1
                            [marker_desc] => Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ne est populo dictas, et pri ferri ubique labitur.

Mel ad euismod adipiscing moderatius eos an decore quodsi animal.
                            [_id] => 6030c28
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: yes that's it. thanks a lot. of course last night i resolved it. but your code is so clear .